# different char font-color in text box

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

For example I have have a text box with the work "eg.'one'"

Is it possible that the font color for "`example`" will be in `color:black` and that the "'one'" will be in `color:red`?

Here is the html:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" Text="example-one"></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/ try this

Comment: i think you need separate "exaple" & "-one" on two TextBox

Comment: Could you tell us an example why you need this?

Comment: You have included ASP code in the question, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only show the text, you should use label:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">
    <span style="color:black">example</span><span style="color:red">-one</span>
</asp:Label>
```

If you need two different texts, you should use two textboxes

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black">example</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red">-one</asp:TextBox>
```

And if you need to user editable, you will have ti use some html editor, like:

http://www.freetextbox.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `<span>` tag, in a label.

```
string s = "example-one";
s = s.Replace("example", "<span style=\"color:black\">example</span>");
s = s.Replace("example", "<span style=\"color:red\">one</span>");
Label1.Text = s;
```

similarly, you could replace each word in the string that you want to add color to with a span tag (eg. replace `example` with `<span style="color:black">example</span>`) in a label.